# PrintWriter create empty file

Tags: java, file-io, printwriter

I have `StringBuilder sb` and I want that string save as `*.txt` file. Problem is that I get `"filename.txt"` but it is completely empty, also there is no errors in console.

Here is my code:

```
System.out.print(sb.toString());
PrintWriter out;
try{
    out = new PrintWriter("filename.txt");
    out.println(sb.toString());
}catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Console output:

```
[19/3/2014]

Ime in priimek: Matjaz Mav
Naslov: Ppot 6, 1000 Ljubljana 
Telefon: 040 111 222

Registerska št.: LJ 1234
Znamka: Citroen
Model: C4
Letnik: 2005
Opombe: Popravi
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Either create your `PrintWriter` with this constructor, changing the first argument to an `OutputStream`:

```
out = new PrintWriter(new FileOutputStream("filename.txt"), true);
```

to turn on auto flushing, or, just close the writer once you're done writing to it with `out.close()`.

Comment: If I try with true in constructor if get following msg: `no suitable constrictor found for PrintWriter(String, boolean)`
Maybe it is because I use NetBeans?
But thanks `out.close();` works perfect :)

Comment: You missed the part about `new FileOutputStream` in the answer

Answer (score 3):

You should use `out.close()` statement in this program.

Answer (score 2):

out.close ();   is missing. 
You have to put it in to close the session.

Answer (score 1):

```
   PrintWriter out;
   try{
       out = new PrintWriter("filename.txt");
       out.println(sb.toString());
       //add the below lines
       out.flush();
       out.close();
   }catch (Exception e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
   }
```

Another way is to have a `PrintWriter` with autoFlush on. That can be achieved by

```
  out = new PrintWriter(new FileOutputStream("filename.txt"), true);
```

If you do only `out.close()` that would also solve the problem at hand as that would `internally flush` the content written in its internal buffer.

Hope this helps.